# Localizing MySQLExceptions

Tags: c#, mysql, exception, localization

The program that I'm working on, my boss would like me to localize everything that the user might see.  This includes `MessageBox`'s.  So, one of my popups is a `MySQLException` that could be anything from "No database selected" to "Table doesn't exist".

My problem is, if it's a table that doesn't exist, I don't want just a generic message.  I want it to say which table doesn't exist.  Currently, this is `MySQL error 1146:  Table '%s.%s' doesn't exist`.  My question is, how can I localize that statement?  Thanks for any and all help.  The code would be something like:

```
switch (ex.Number)
{
    case 1146:
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); // Currently shows "Table Database.Table doesn't exist
        break;
}
```

But the message would be localized to the language of the user.

Comment: why don't you just gracefully handle the the `MySqlException`?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't be displaying raw error messges to end-users at all.

Comment: @SLaks: I'm not displaying the raw message.  I want the message to be "Table X doesn't exist." But I don't know what the table is.

Comment: @prayos: "localization" usually means displaying language-specific error messages. you just want a customized error.

Comment: @MarcB: Currently, if I output `ex.Message`, the pop up says "Table Database.Table doesn't exist".  That is the part that I want to show in the correct language.

Comment: The message that comes back from mysql is based on the culture of the mysql installation.  C# has no control over that.  If you want to internationalize that you will have to do it yourself, by getting an internationalized string and inserting the table name extracted from the error message by `Substring` or `Regex` or whatever works best.  You're obviously not going to be able to internationalize the name, because it's a name.

Comment: @YYY: So you're saying that MySQL is responsible for the language that the exception comes back in?

Comment: @Prayos In this case it is, yeah.  To illustrate the point, try running `Select * from dbo.NonExistantTable` on your mySQL server and note that the error you get back is the same as what's going up in your program.  Or, to put it another way, do you think Microsoft REALLY wants to be responsible for making different errors for everything that can go wrong on a mySQL server, or would they rather just parse the standard returns into a typed exception? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it both on server-side and client-side...

[**Client-side**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-message-language.html)

```
SET lc_messages='en_US';
```

[**Server-side**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835147/change-mysql-error-message-language)

Find this line in your my.cnf

```
lc-messages=<...>
```

and set it to fulfill your desires...