# Change MySQL error message language

Tags: mysql

I have problem with MySQL Error Language. When query has some error then that error is not in English. It is like below message

```
Le champ 'id' ne peut Ãªtre vide (null)
```

I have run this query to change language but still same error

```
SET lc_messages = 'en_US';
```

How can I change error message to English?

Comment: if you want to permanently change language change my.ini file lc-messages=en_US

Comment: Please close the question

Comment: I think it should not be close may be it is useful for others.

Comment: you should post and answer then I will accept that.

Comment: Accept the answer so that it will be useful for others

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change the following settings in my.ini file

```
lc-messages=en_US
```

To permanently change the language preferences

Comment: Don't forget to restart the services after this.

Answer (score 4):

Change the following settings in my.ini file

[image: im]

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can change the language for such error messages during the runtime!

According to [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-message-language.html):

> `lc_messages` can be set at server startup and has global and session
>   values that can be modified at runtime. Thus, the error message
>   language can be changed while the server is running, and each client
>   can have its own error message language by setting its session
>   `lc_messages` value to the desired locale name. For example, if the
>   server is using the `fr_FR` locale for error messages, a client can
>   execute this statement to receive error messages in English:

```
SET lc_messages = 'en_US'
```

Just tried it, and it actually works!

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is to just clear your browser's cookies.