# how localize error messages from database

Tags: mysql, database

After executing a statement (CREATE/UPDATE/DROP/INSERT) on a database, is there a way we can localize the error messages thrown by the database, if any, and show them on UI?

Comment: Is this answer any helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28749929/4732334 ?

Comment: Thank you, @IldarAkhmetov it's useful. But, I want to change the locale of error messages at run time whenever the user changes preferences from UI. Could this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, yes, you can do it.

According to [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-message-language.html):

> `lc_messages` can be set at server startup and has global and session
>   values that can be modified at runtime. Thus, the error message
>   language can be changed while the server is running, and each client
>   can have its own error message language by setting its session
>   `lc_messages` value to the desired locale name. For example, if the
>   server is using the `fr_FR` locale for error messages, a client can
>   execute this statement to receive error messages in English:

```
SET lc_messages = 'en_US'
```

Just tried it, and it actually works!

Comment: @Suneel Please accept the answer if it solved your problem :)